# Windows 7/8/10 cmd or powershell find lines in a txt file that are longer or smaller than X characters

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, regex

In windows 7/8/10 is there a way to quickly find in a txt file all the lines that are longer or smaller than X (let's say 418) characters?
I heard I can do it with Notepad++, but I'm looking for a solution in cmd or PowerShell.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a PowerShell script you can use `Get-Content` in combination with a `Where-Object`:

```
Get-Content .\input.txt | ?{$_.length -le 418}
```

This would print all lines that are less than or equal to 418 characters long for a file called `input.txt`.

Comment: this is a very convenient solution. question mark is short for where-object?

Comment: Yes and `$_` references the current item.